# Treemap with plotly in R Non-sense percentages

Tags: r, plotly

Hello I'm trying to do a tree map by dividing on 2 segments a 100%, split in 50% and 50% with this code:

```
labels = c("TOTAL","PARTE 1", "PARTE 2")
parents = c("","TOTAL","TOTAL")
values=c(100,50,50)
values = values

plot_ly(
  type="treemap",
  labels=labels,
  parents=parents,
  values=values,
  textinfo="label+value+percent parent",
  domain=list(column=0)
)
```

But it seems to by splitted in 25%'s why is this?

[image]

On a second Step I would like to sub-divide the totals, on a kind of funnel:

```
labels = c("TOTAL","PARTE 1", "PARTE 2","PARTE 1-A","PARTE 1-B", "PARTE 2-A")
parents = c("","TOTAL","TOTAL","PARTE 1","PARTE 1","PARTE 2")
values=c(100,50,50,25,25,50) %>% as.character()
values = values

plot_ly(
  type="treemap",
  labels=labels,
  parents=parents,
  values=values,
  textinfo="label+value+percent parent",
  domain=list(column=10)
)
```

[image]

But 25/50 = 50% and it is displaying 25% for "PARTE 1", and in "PARTE 2" 50/50 = 100% but it is just displaying 50%... what is wrong?

Also, when I add more percentages, any of them are the numbers I look for:

```
labels = c("TOTAL","PARTE 1", "PARTE 2","PARTE 1-A","PARTE 1-B", "PARTE 2-A")
parents = c("","TOTAL","TOTAL","PARTE 1","PARTE 1","PARTE 2")
values=c(100,50,50,25,25,50) %>% as.character()
values = values

plot_ly(
  type="treemap",
  labels=labels,
  parents=parents,
  values=values,
  textinfo="label+value+percent parent+percent entry+percent root",
  domain=list(column=10)
)
```

[image]

Because, for example "PARTE 1-A" = 25 which is the 25% of the Total which is equal to 100, and the 50% of "PARTE 1" which is equal to 50. And none of these numbers are being displayed here.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it! it is just a matter of specifying a parameter:

`branchvalues="total"`

```
labels = c("TOTAL","PARTE 1", "PARTE 2","PARTE 1-A","PARTE 1-B", "PARTE 2-A")
parents = c("","TOTAL","TOTAL","PARTE 1","PARTE 1","PARTE 2")
values=c(100,50,50,25,25,50) %>% as.character()
values = values

plot_ly(
  type="treemap",
  labels=labels,
  parents=parents,
  values=values,
  branchvalues="total",
  textinfo="label+value+percent parent+percent entry+percent root",
  domain=list(column=10)
)
```

[image]